# H2 Database error -

Tags: java, h2

When I run a script to start the H2 database, I get the following output:

```
java -cp h2-1.4.191.jar org.h2.tools.Server -
tcp -tcpAllowOthers -tcpPort 40000
Error: Could not find or load main class org.h2.tools.Server
```

The contents of the script I ran is:

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin

```
java -cp h2-1.4.191.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -tcpPort 40000
```

The database worked fine until I closed the application and started it again.

I did not try to restart the server, since it is running other important applications. What can the issue be or will the best solution be to reboot the server?

Comment: try to Embed it with your application or add this in your path variable `C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin` or else make this `java -cp h2-1.4.191.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -tcpPort 40000`  as service

Comment: The error `Could not find or load main class org.h2.tools.Server` means java could not find the class within the classpath you supplied. Are you sure you're changing to the right directory? Maybe you should enclose the directory path in quotes: `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin"`